# Effect of IV across multiple levels of covariates (similar to ANCOVA) for dichotomous outcome

Tags: logistic, interaction, ancova

tldr: ANCOVA shows you a main effect for your IV across all levels of the covariate, while removing variance attributable to the covariate. Regression shows you the effect of the IV at the reference level of the covariate plus interaction term(s) for the other level(s). In the case where the outcome is dichotomous, is there any way to get an ANCOVA-style main effect?

---

Consider a dataset with a dichotomous IV, a categorical covariate, and a continuous DV. For example, here's the `iris` dataset with `Species` as the IV and a dichotomized `Sepal.Width` as a covariate:

```
iris <- iris %>% 
    filter(Species != "setosa") %>% 
    mutate(sepal_bin = factor(ntile(iris$Sepal.Width, 2)))
lm_model <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Species * sepal_bin, data=iris)
summary(lm_model)

Coefficients:
                            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                  4.10645    0.08762  46.867  < 2e-16 ***
Speciesvirginica             1.26723    0.14214   8.916 3.17e-14 ***
sepal_bin2                   0.40407    0.14214   2.843  0.00546 ** 
Speciesvirginica:sepal_bin2 -0.11647    0.20101  -0.579  0.56367
```

The significance test for species only considers the effect at the reference level of sepal_bin. As I understand it, there's no equivalent to the main effect from an ANCOVA model, which tests the combined effect of the species across the whole dataset, while still subtracting variance that can be attributed to sepal_bin:

```
aov_model <- aov(Petal.Length ~ Species * sepal_bin, data=iris)
summary(aov_model)

                   Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)    
Species            1  41.73   41.73 175.351 < 2e-16 ***
sepal_bin          1   2.82    2.82  11.840 0.00086 ***
Species:sepal_bin  1   0.08    0.08   0.336 0.56367    
Residuals         96  22.85    0.24
```

---

I'm doing an analysis similar to this one, except that **the DV is dichotomous**. The usual solution is to use logistic regression. However, **I want to do a significance test for the effect of the IV across the whole dataset, not just at the reference level of the covariate**. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is [car::Anova()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/car/versions/2.1-5/topics/Anova). It can take the output from a logistic regression, as well as many other types of model, and recompute it into a type II or III analysis of variance table.

In my example above, `car::Anova(lm_model)` will take a linear or logistic multiple regression and provide an analysis of variance table formatted exactly like the ANOVA result shown in my question, including a main effect estimated across all levels of the covariate(s). This is exactly what I wanted.